# Is [company] breaching any data protection legislation in Canada needing my wife's details to authenticate MY account?

Tags: data-protection

I created an online account in my name with a large Canadian retailer. My wife enters her credit card details to pay for the shopping. When I log in to the website it greets me with my name.

When I call customer services however, they ask for the name of the customer. I give them my name. They always insist on talking to my wife about MY account because it's her name on the credit card - it seems they have chosen the incorrect field for the customer's name.

Is this company in the wrong? Are they in breach of any data protection legislation?

I would just like to be able to talk to them about my own account!

Comment: How do you expect them to know that the cardholder authorises your use of her card, and that she is your wife? What if she is not your wife, or even if she is, she does not authorise you to use the card? Why not to let her tell it the company and ask them to speak to you only from there on?

Comment: The issue here is the definition of customer. Is it the person who places the order, or the person who pays? Logically you are the one entering into a contract.